# We've got to public beta! Did you notice?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, beta

Great news - we've entered public beta, in a week. Congratulations to all of us for reaching this milestone.

I've been on beta sites that subsequently failed, and they took a fair bit longer to exit private beta. So I take it as a very healthy sign that we've exited private beta nice and early.

Now's the time to start forwarding the site URL to friends, colleagues, and relevant mailing lists, in an appropriate non-spammy manner.

So did you notice we've gone public?

Comment: Congratuations!